# Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Am trying to parse a json response but I have this error and I don't know why. The error occurs inside the Data object. Because when I remove the object it works perfectly. I need to know what am doing wrong.

```
class TripDetails {
  String operatorId;
  String title;
  String body;
  Data data;

  TripDetails({this.operatorId, this.title, this.body, this.data});

  TripDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    operatorId = json['operatorId'];
    title = json['title'];
    body = json['body'];
    data = json['data'] != null ? new Data.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
  }

}

class Data {
  String clickAction;
  String tripId;
  String tripType;
  String date;
  String earning;
  String distance;
  String stores;

  Data(
      {this.clickAction,
        this.tripId,
        this.tripType,
        this.date,
        this.earning,
        this.distance,
        this.stores});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    clickAction = json['click_action'];
    tripId = json['tripId'];
    tripType = json['trip_type'];
    date = json['date'];
    earning = json['earning'];
    distance = json['distance'];
    stores = json['stores'];
  }
```

This is the data am trying to parse. The problem occurs inside the data object.

```
{
  "operatorId": "W5u8Bz2oeIMM32I8ZSanreKvwLk2",
  "title": "Hoole",
  "body": "New Trip Request",
  "data": {
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    "tripId": "12131131",
    "trip_type": "trip",
    "date":"12343325",
    "earning":"123.54",
    "distance":"123",
    "stores":"[{\"id\":\"pnp1\",\"name\":\"Pick n Pay\",\"logo\":\"https://example.com\"}, {\"id\":\"woolies1\",\"name\":\"Woolworths\",\"logo\":\"https://example.com\"}]"
  }
}
```

Comment: Post the code of parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
```

to this:

```
Data.fromJson(Map json) {
```